# Pioneer BDR-207D disappeared after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, blu-ray

My blu-ray player has vanished after the upgrade. It doesn't show up at all in the device manager. Tried running the firmware update tool for the blu-ray player, but it says it can't find a device (of course).

The device can be seen in the BIOS though.

[image]

Any thoughts on how to get it back?

---

Update: I tried renaming `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\UpperFilters`, but it didn't solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by switching SATA port on the motherboard for the Blu-ray player.